# Assert that two labels are less than N bytes apart in NASM

Tags: x86, nasm

In NASM, can I compile-time assert that two labels are less than N bytes apart?

I.e., something like:

```
label1:
; some code
; goes here
label2:

; here I want to check that the distance between label1 and label2 is less than 50 bytes...
```

The issue should be caught at compile-time, ideally with an understandable error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the labels occur before the check, this should work:

```
label1:
resb 50  ; For testing purposes
label2:

%if (label2 - label1) >= 50
%error "Blah blah blah"
%endif
```